# How to change time on local NTP server and distribute to others?

Tags: ntp, time, time-synchronization

Is there any solution to retrieve time from a NTP server and change time locally (Increase or decrease) and then distribute new time to other servers?
As an example, server retrieve UTC time and change it +1 (Or increase by one hour) and then distribute increased time to others automatically as a NTP server.

Comment: You want to distribute the wrong time?

Comment: Yes, Our application needs GMT+1 instead of local time. we need to solution for converting UTC to current time +1 and distribute the localtime of this server to the others.

Comment: Why don't you just set the time zone?

Comment: There is a solution to this, it's called "correct timezone setting". It's possible to set it per server and nothing on your NTP has to be changed. UTC ist just a universal time and will be coverted according to the local timezone setting.

Answer (score 3):

Configure operating system and applications to use time zones.

Do not alter NTP. NTP has no mechanism for time zone style offsets.

Comment: I want time synchronization between our internal NTP server with external NTP sever but forward time as current time+1hour to other servers with UTC timezone.

Comment: Time zone still isn't a thing in NTP. Users configuring a time zone offset will not get what they expect. If you connect to not broken NTP servers, your time may step a large offset.